# Composite key class relationship → ERROR: not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

CVariacaoTO class has a composite key (FK_T, FK_F, FK_F_VARIACAO).
(FK_F, FK_F_VARIACAO) are also foreign key to FVariacaoTO table, in a ManyToOne relationship.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_F", referencedColumnName = "FK_F", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_F_V", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
@NotNull
private FVariacaoTO fVariacaoTO;
```

FVariacaoTO class has two primary keys, into a @Embeddable class FVariacaoPK.

This ERROR has ocurred: referencedColumnNames(FK_F, ID) of CVariacaoTO.fVariacaoTO not mapped to a single property

Relationship is just described in CVariacaoTO class. 
I don't know if a need write something about relationship in FVariacaoTO class, making @OneToMany or something like that.

What usually done this error?
How usually is done this kind of relationship?

---

EDIT: additional info.

In the FVariacaoTO class, the key is as @EmbeddedId:

`@EmbeddedId 
@AttributeOverrides({ 
@AttributeOverride(name = "fkF", column = @Column(name = "fkF", nullable = false)), 
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)) }) 
@NotNull 
private FVariacaoPK fVariacaoPK;`

In the FVariacaoPK class, that have this @EmbeddedId:

`@Column(name = "FK_F", nullable = false) private int fkF;`

`@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false) private int id;`

Answer (score 0):

Not yet could run the application because there are other problems to be solved, but doing the next way the compiler no longer complain about this issue:

`@JoinColumn(name = "FK_F", referencedColumnName = "fkF", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_F_V", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)`

I set in referencedColumnName the field name in FVariacaoTO instead @Embedabble object in FVariacaoPK

Comment: What if I have EmbeddedId at both parent and child side(both has different columns), and I want to map OneToMany from Parent to Child. I can't use @JoinColumns as one column is not at both end. and not working with mappedBy also... any idea?

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar any update on your last question? Are you able to run with the requirement mentioned?